# Change ng-modal input value with another input in-modal

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ngmodel

I want to change value of an input which has its `ng-model` from another input `ng-model` value. It does not do so. `ng-model="quantity"` is in the `ng-repeat`, and `ng-model="power"` is outside of `ng-repeat`. So when I change value in `power` so the all `quantity` should change accordingly.

e.g

```
 <input type="text" ng-model="quantity" value="{{quantity * power}}">
 <input type="text" ng-model="power" value="{{power}}">
```

Comment: Can you include all of your code? The `ng-repeat` as well as the controller would be ideal... based off of what you showed I can't quite tell what you're trying to do.

Comment: Please give your  ng-repeat code.

Comment: demo code is here below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this.

```js
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('mainCtrl', function ($scope) {
        $scope.quantities = [25, 6, 6.5, 80];
        $scope.quantitiesNewValue = [25, 6, 6.5, 80];
        $scope.power = 1;
 
   $scope.setValue = function(power){
      angular.forEach($scope.quantities, function(quantity,i){
         $scope.quantitiesNewValue[i] = power * quantity;
        });
     }
                 
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="mainCtrl">
<h1>NG-MODEL Sample</h1>
<p><input type="text" ng-model="power" ng-change="setValue(power)" value="{{power}}" /></p>
<div ng-repeat="quantity in quantitiesNewValue">
Quantity: <input type="text" ng-model="quantity" />
</div>
```

Comment: I tried this, and came with another problem that it permanent set values of the original array so when I want to multiply another number it further multiply instead of re-multiply the original array.

Comment: can you have duplicate array?

Answer (score 0):

You have two mistakes in html.

1) In first input field you have for `power` you should have given power in ng-model, where you have typo as well ng-mode would be ng-model

`ng-model="power"` instead of `ng-mode="p`enter code here`ower"`

2) In ng-repeat block the `ng-model` should be expression (`quantity*power`) not only quantity

`ng-model="quantity*power"` instead of `ng-model="quantity"`

[Live Demo](http://jsbin.com/cewehuguli/edit?html,js,output)

Your html would be

```
<h1>NG-MODEL Sample</h1>
<p><input type="text" ng-model="power" value="{{power}}" /></p>
<div ng-repeat="quantity in quantities">
     Quantity: <input type="text" ng-model="quantity*power" value="{{quantity *         power}}"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks it worked for me perfectly what I wanted. and Yes I made those mistakes posting the question. But I forwarded my idea and you solved it very nicely.